# MacOS FTP connection closes when I try to list files on the remote ftp server

Tags: ftp, macos-ventura

I am working on **Ventura 13.0 MacOS**. When opening a terminal to connect with FTP, I am able to log on to the FTP site successfully but when I execute an `ls` command, the connection fails.

I can ping the FTP server with no problems. I can also use FileZilla and connect to the site with no issues. So, I wanted to reach out to the group and ask if anyone has also encountered this issue and found a solution for it. Thanks.

Tterminal example after I logged on:

```
230 Logged on
ftp> ls
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection
ftp: No control connection for command
```

Comment: Try toggle between Active and Passive mide.  FTP is a horrible protocol which requires multiple ports, and there are issues negotiating the second port.

Comment: @davidgo You were right about the Passive mode. I turned passive mode on and it worked. thank you.